# Laravel 5.3 Default Authentication Styles not applying

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I created a fresh laravel 5.3 project inside my xampp localhost environment. I went to the home page and it appeared as usual, with the pretty styles and all. 
But there is the new artisan command `make:auth` that sets-up a functioning registration system. But when I go to the register or login page, it should appear with the pretty styles, but instead it's appearing like this:

[image]

Any help?

Comment: make sure that the app.css is being included, in your chrome view source and see if the stylesheet is there

Comment: Take a look at your browser console. My guess is you have a problem with absolute vs relative links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

-Make sure that you are extending the master layout file(the default or your custom one)

-changes links like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('css/mycss')">
```

Share more code please if this did not work (folder structure , register.php)

Comment: New laravel 5.3 doesn't have the views and something is wrong...in 5.2.* everything was fine....they changed something

Comment: nah im using laravel 5.3 and it's fine, yet changes might happend im not 100% sure since i think they are going to make a scaffold with vue.js or something like this

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case I noticed that my app.css was empty. Solved it by using the following commands:

```
php artisan auth vue
npm install
npm run dev
```

Reference that I used for this problem with Laravel 6: [Laravel 6.0 app.js only has require('.bootstrap');?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57888300/laravel-6-0-app-js-only-has-require-bootstrap)