# Laravel 6.0 app.js only has require('.bootstrap');?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I just started learning how to work with a `Laravel` server and I want to use `Vue`. But after installing the `app.js` file only has `require('/bootstrap');` in it, shouldn't it have the required components and the const app field?

I used `npm install` and `npm run watch`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel 6 doesn't ship with frontend scaffolding anymore, they shipped that to a new package called [Laravel UI](https://github.com/laravel/ui) so install it and scaffold VueJS

```sh
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue
```

And if you need the authentication views like `login` and `register`

```sh
php artisan ui vue --auth
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/frontend#introduction)